# Erlang: turn pid into string

Tags: erlang

I want to turn a Pid in erlang <0.121.0> into a string, how would I do this?

Is there a way to pattern match against a Pid?

```
{Node, Index, Number} = <0.121.0>.
```

Comment: For node identification use [node/1](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#node-1) instead.

Comment: Can you explain why you want this? Sounds like you're trying to solve something the wrong way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pid_tokens(Pid) ->
    PidStr = pid_to_list(Pid),
    PidStr1 = lists:sublist(PidStr, 2, length(PidStr)-2),
    [N, P1, P2] = [list_to_integer(T) || T <- string:tokens(PidStr1,[$.])],
    {N, P1, P2}.
```

Something like this may work for you. Where Pid is process id you want to match

Comment: Be careful, though. `This BIF is intended for debugging and for use in the Erlang operating system. It should not be used in application programs.`

Comment: @tkowal any idea what the risks are?

Comment: You just shouldn't depend on Pid internal structure, because it may change without warning. `pid_to_list` and `list_to_pid` are handy during debugging, when you copy and paste pids in the shell. The only moment, where it could be handy in real program is checking, if the process is on remote node. There is another function for that: `node(Pid)`.

Comment: Thanks @tkowal when you say "because it may change without warning" what would be an example of this?

Comment: I don't know :) Anything! For example, they could be displayed as two integers, instead of three. Or the separator might be changed from dot to comma :) Or someone might want to use 64 bits for pids, so there will be more numbers in string representation... I don't think there are any plans to change it for now. But if the docs say, "don't depend on it", I'd rather avoid it in application code :)